# R text mining - removing stopwords in different language cause aumlet problems

Tags: r, character-encoding, text-mining

I am starting to use text mining in R.

I ran into such proplem that when using tm_map function for stopwords in another language than english, aumlets are not showing properly.

Example:

```
#Test
a<-"Ääkkösiä paljon, että toiminta selviää."
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(a))
inspect(docs)

# This causes problems:
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("finnish"))

dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
d
```

Whitouth tm_map, it shows like this:

```
             word freq
että         että    1
paljon     paljon    1
selviää   selviää    1
toiminta toiminta    1
ääkkösiä ääkkösiä    1
```

With tm_map the result is different. The word "että" should be removed, because it is a stopword in finnish. Also here aumlets collapses:

```
             word freq
kkÃ           kkÃ    1
paljon     paljon    1
selviÃ     selviÃ    1
siÃ           siÃ    1
toiminta toiminta    1
```

Comment: `tm_map` is not the problem. If you do `inspect(docs)` after `tm_map` you will see that everything is fine. But as soon as you use `TermDocumentMatrix` you have a problem (at least when you are on windows). I tend to use tidytext or quanteda or udpipe due to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I use other means to handle the subject.